# AJAX request to WCF service secured by ADFS

Tags: ajax, wcf, adfs

I configured authentication on my web site via ADFS. Some services are hosted on site. I have a problem with AJAX requests to these services (Bad request 400). Is it possible to configure binding for service to process ajax requests?

```
...    
<bindings>
        <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
                <binding name="" >
                  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message establishSecurityContext="false">
                      <issuerMetadata address="https://example.com/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
                    </message>
                  </security>
                </binding>
              </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
   ....     
                <services>
                  <service name="ServiceName"
                           behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                    <endpoint name="FederationHttpBinding"
                              address=""
                              binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
                              contract="ServiceContract"/>
                  </service>
            </services>
       .... 
              <system.identityModel>
                <identityConfiguration>
                  <audienceUris>
                    <add value="https://example.com:447/" />
                  </audienceUris>
                  <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
                    <authority name="http://example.com/adfs/services/trust">
                      <keys>
                        <add thumbprint="6A5123456789A40F9123456789CFF34" />
                      </keys>
                      <validIssuers>
                        <add name="http://example.com/adfs/services/trust" />
                      </validIssuers>
                    </authority>
                  </issuerNameRegistry>
                  <!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
                  <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
                  <securityTokenHandlers>
                    <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                    <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                  </securityTokenHandlers>
                </identityConfiguration>
              </system.identityModel>
              <system.identityModel.services>
                <federationConfiguration>
                  <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
                  <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true"
                                issuer="https://example.com/adfs/ls/"
                                realm="https://example.com:447"
                                requireHttps="false" />
                </federationConfiguration>
              </system.identityModel.services>
```